# Mouseover image stays the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this code
I'll explain a little how this works,

The idea of this is that when hovering in tag (`a`), change the image of the `id="meal"`, by the one that is in the (`data-meal = "meal-14"`) .. in a few words

The pre-determined image is meal-0.png, hover in tag (`a`) with (`data-meal = 14`), replaces the url of the image with (meal-14.png),

Everything works fine, I only have one problem and is that when you stop hovering, do not go back to the pre-determined image, it stays in the image that became hover. Should return to the image meal-0.png.

```
 <div class="imagen-hover" id="meal">
        <img src="/public/tienda/meal-0.png" alt="">
    </div>  

    <ul>
<li><a class="carne-a" data-meal="meal-14">14. Punta de Anca</a></li>
<li><a class="carne-a" data-meal="meal-16">16. Chata Angosta</a></li>
    </ul>


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var path = "/public/images/";
            $(".meal-a").on("mouseover", function() {
                var meal = $(this).attr("data-meal") + ".png";
                $("#meal img").attr("src", path + meal)

            });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is because it is doing exactly what you told it to do.

you need to make another event handler for `mouseleave`

or you can look at the jQuery docs , mouseenter can take two call backs , one for entering and one for leaving

```
        $(".meal-a").mouseenter( function() {
            var meal = $(this).attr("data-meal") + ".png";
            $("#meal img").attr("src", path + meal)

        }).mouseleave( function() { //for when mouse leaves
            });
```

What I would recommend though... you do not need javascript or jQuery at all for this , there is a css selector for while the user is hovering over an element

```
 .meal-a{ // regular code
  }
 .meal-a:hover{ // hover code
 }
```

Comment: yes, It is not necessary js, but many images, I would have to repeat a lot of code

Comment: that's not completely true , there are ways to share code written in css just like javascript .  Also  - don't forget that `hover` and `mouseenter` aren't gonig to do anything on mobile touch devices

Comment: consider adding an option for mobile as well , maybe tapping the image should change the state

Comment: Yes! @scott-selby

Answer (score 2):

Also add a "mouseout" function to handle returning the image to its previous value

```
$(".meal-a").on("mouseout", function() {
     $("#meal img").attr("src", "meal-0.png")
});
```